# How do I convert a float in the format of xxxxxxxe+09 to an int in Go?

Tags: go

Given a number like 1.400126761e+09 in Golang, what can I use to cast it to an int? I tried using the strconv library to play around with it and convert it using FormatFloat but that function returns the same thing when I give it the 'e' flag. Any other functions/libraries that will handle this conversion to an int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use int(). For example:

```
x := float32(3.1)
fmt.Println(int(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

`ParseFloat` is not returning the same thing, it's returning a `float64` or `float32`. After you use it, you can just convert to an int as usual:

```
s := "1.400126761e+09"
f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(s, 64)
if err == nil {
    thisisanint := int(f)
    fmt.Println(thisisanint)
} else {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/IFoqcMj2ji)

Answer (score 0):

I actually was not clear as the variable I was playing with employs the interface{} and simply needed a float64 type assertion before casting it like int(). Hope this helps!